# How to find a "piece" of word in a string with regex and using it in python?

Tags: python, regex

For a holiday homework, in a password-check python program, I'd like to use *regexs* to find if the name (or a "piece" of the name, **meaning 2 consecutive letters**) of the user is contained into a password he provided.

### Part 1: the regex itself

Let's say the user is named *Samuel*:

- password that would match:

  ```
  samuel
  sAm123
  123Sam
  lSAMUo
  sa
  ```
- password that wouldn't match:

  ```
  s3m
  leumas
  sml
  s123
  ```

So far, I've only succeeded to do this incomplete regex:

```
[sS]?[aA]?[mM]?[uU]?[eE]?[lL]?
```

But it matches if there is only one letter from the regex in the password and also when it's not 2 consecutive letters.

***How can I enhance the regex?***

### Part 2: the python use

When I use the `search` function from `re` package, it only matches my previous regex if it's at the begening of the string. Here is a sample code of a case that should work:

```
import re
reg = r"[sS]?[aA]?[mM]?[uU]?[eE]?[lL]?"
re.match(reg, "samuel")  # Match
re.match(reg, "sml")  # Match
re.match(reg, "123sam")  # Doesn't match
re.match(reg, "zzzSAmu")  # Doesn't match
```

***What am I missing?***

Comment: This might be helpful for testing regexp: [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Do you mean `(?: sa | am | mu | ue | el )` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
import re

pattern = r"(?i)sa|am|mu|ue|el"
for _string in ("samuel", "sAm123", "1235Sam", "lSAMUo", "sa"):
    assert re.search(pattern, _string) is not None

for _string in ("s3m", "leumas", "sml", "s123"):
    assert re.search(pattern, _string) is None
```

The main takes here are:

- use `re.search()` rather than `re.match()`, as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) puts it:

  > If you want to locate a match anywhere in string, use search() instead (see also search() vs. match()).
- `(?i)` makes the regex case insensitive

Credits to @sin for suggesting using pairs of characters in the question's comments